# Kann ich mir vorstellen

Tags: grammar-identification

> Kann ich mir vorstellen

I have heard this sentence many times from German natives but I am confused as it is in the form of a question but actually means like a declarative sentence.

The meaning I read is "Can I imagine that?" but the intended meaning is "I can imagine that"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> (Das) kann ich mir vorstellen.

In an interrogative sentence, the verb comes first. But here, the verb is not really first. The "correct" sentence is "Das kann ich mir vorstellen.". The "Das" is omitted.

> Kann ich mir [das] vorstellen?

Here the structure is like in an interrogative sentence. The "das" cannot be omitted.
So you got the structure right. It is the "lazy" German speakers who confuse you.

Comment: As an addition, this kind of ellipsis is very common in German.

Answer (score 1):

There are many colloquial sentences like yours:

*Kenn ich.* = Das kenne ich (schon).

*Könnte sein.* = Das könnte sein, das wäre möglich.

*Hab' ich (schon).* = Den/Die/Das hab(e) ich schon.

*Ist einfach so! / Ist so!* = Das ist Fakt.

*Ging nicht anders, sorry.* = Es gab keine andere Möglichkeit für mich.

*Hätte glatt von mir sein können.* = Ich denke genauso.

*Hätt' ich mir ja denken können.* = I might have guessed.

*Kommt drauf an.* = Das kommt darauf an.

*Hab' verstanden. / Verstanden.* = Ich habe verstanden.

*Brauchst du nicht.* = You need not do it.

*Macht nichts. / Macht nix.* = Kein Problem, heute sagt man "Alles gut.".

and so on.

In addition to such colloquialisms and yes/no questions, there are other types of sentences with the initial position of the verb:

- Aufforderungen im Imperativ: *Kommen Sie!* (= Folgen Sie mir.)
- Wunschsätze: *Hätte ich doch etwas gesagt!* = If only I had said
  something!
- Ausrufesätze: *Bist **du** aber groß geworden!*
- irreale Konditionalsätze ohne Konjunktion: *Hättest du auf mich
  gehört, wäre das nicht passiert.*

Conclusion: Es gibt viele Verb-1-Sätze, die keine Ja/nein-Fragen sind.